# Use Maven Plugin parameter value as default value of another parameter

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Do someone know if it's possible to set a maven plugin parameter default value to the value of another parameter of the same Mojo ?

```
@Parameter(required = true, defaultValue = "1")
private int param1;

// works fine
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.basedir}")
private File param2;

// here I want param3 to be default to param1 if not set
// @Parameter(defaultValue = "${param1}") doesn't work
// @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.param1}") doesn't work
// @Parameter(defaultValue = "1") not what I want
@Parameter
private int param3;
```

I want param3 to be equals to param1 if the value of param3 is not provided by the plugin's configuration... Is this possible ?

Comment: What is the purpose of that? Why do you need two parameters which are filled with the same value? Can you describe more in detail what you like to achieve?

Comment: In fact param1 is required and represent the number of time a transform should be applied to File param2. I want by defaut to archive each transform (param1 value) but for some reason we might not want to archive each transform but only the n-last / or n-first / or zero which is the reason for the optionnal param3...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible with the current annotations. I suggest to write a getter for `param3` which contains the necessary magic and then always use the getter in your code.